# Android - Retrofit json parsing

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have following json array. I want to parse it in android using retrofit

```
[
  {
    "todo_id": "1",
    "todo_content": "Homework",
    "date": "2016-05-05",
    "iscomplete": "1",
    "imagelink": "Lighthouse.jpg"
  },
  {
    "todo_id": "2",
    "todo_content": "exam",
    "date": "2015-04-21",
    "iscomplete": "0",
    "imagelink": "Desert.jpg"
  },
  {
    "todo_id": "3",
    "todo_content": "Lab report",
    "date": "2014-08-29",
    "iscomplete": "1",
    "imagelink": "FB_IMG_14700753538617403.jpg"
  }
]
```

when I'm using retrofit for json parsing but it do not parse todo_id and todo_content key values where as it show other key values date, iscomplete and imagelink
This is my android code for retrofit response

```
 public void onResponse(Call<List<AndroidVersion>> call, Response<List<AndroidVersion>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                                AndroidVersion ver = new AndroidVersion();
                                ver.setTodoContent(response.body().get(i).getTodoContent());
                                ver.setTodoId(response.body().get(i).getTodoId());
                                ver.setDate(response.body().get(i).getDate());
                                ver.setIscomplete(response.body().get(i).getIscomplete());
                                ver.setImagelink(response.body().get(i).getImagelink());
                                arrayList.add(ver);
                                Log.v("ret",response.body().get(i).toString());
                            }
                            adapter = new DataAdapter(arrayList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: please post your AndroidVersion Class

Comment: Use @SerializedName for parsing, than your fields should match json names. Put json field name in the annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("todo_id")
@Expose
private String todoId;
@SerializedName("todo_content")
@Expose
private String todoContent;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("iscomplete")
@Expose
private String iscomplete;
@SerializedName("imagelink")
@Expose
private String imagelink;

public String getTodoId() {
return todoId;
}

public void setTodoId(String todoId) {
this.todoId = todoId;
}

public String getTodoContent() {
return todoContent;
}

public void setTodoContent(String todoContent) {
this.todoContent = todoContent;
}

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getIscomplete() {
return iscomplete;
}

public void setIscomplete(String iscomplete) {
this.iscomplete = iscomplete;
}

public String getImagelink() {
return imagelink;
}

public void setImagelink(String imagelink) {
this.imagelink = imagelink;
}

}
```

It should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Use Serialized name.

Your json response is having parameter name "todo_id" so in your pojo class you have to mention it as it is, follow the example of the pojo class:

```
public class Pojo {
    private int todo_id;
    private String todo_content;

    public int getTodo_id() {
        return todo_id;
    }

    public void setTodo_id(int todo_id) {
        this.todo_id = todo_id;
    }

    public String getTodo_content() {
        return todo_content;
    }

    public void setTodo_content(String todo_content) {
        this.todo_content = todo_content;
    }

}
```

The names should match.. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great...!!! You can use GSON Format plugin in andorid studio itslef, it create pojo class in serialized format.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this link](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) and paste your response there to generate appropriate POJO class for your response. This will generate getter and setter methods as well. Hope this helps.